# VB.net Find Sending Control in module

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, module

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to create a multi userform application.  The userforms will have buttons of which some (from the different forms) will all go to the same module.  I need to figure out (within the module) how to determine which button from which form is the sender.  I know how to find the sender on the form itself by using sender and handles but I'm stumped as to how to find the sender when I'm in the module.

Thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: I'll suspend my judgement on how bad an idea this sounds like.  Can you please provide an example of what this method in the module will look like and how you are tying it to the events?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the sender into your module as a parameter.

```
Public Module Module1
    Public Function MyFunction(sender As Button)
        ' do stuff with sender here
    End Function
End Module
```

That's what function parameters are for.

Comment: If its just buttons, you can declare it as Button, otherwise theres going to be a need to cast the sender, turn option strict on...